# How to access the click (desktop) / tap (mobile) position using the new input system?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a new Unity project and installed the package for the new Input system. Basically I just want to store the position of a click (desktop) / tap (mobile), that's it.

I know the old system provides solutions

- https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html
- https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-position.html

but I want to solve it with the new input system.

I started with this input map configuration (I will show the configuration for each selected item)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I created a new script logging each click/tap position

```
public class FooBar : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Select(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        Vector2 selectPosition = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        Debug.Log($"Select position is: {selectPosition.x}|{selectPosition.y}");
    }
}
```

In the scene I created an empty gameobject and configured it in the inspector

[image]

Unfortunately when running the playmode I get these errors each time when moving the mouse around

[image]

This is the stacktrace of the first error message

[image]

and this is the stacktrace of the second error message

[image]

So I'm assuming my input map configuration is wrong.

Would someone mind helping me setting up an input configuration passing the click/tap position to the script?

---

So for a quick workaround I currently use this code with the old input system but I really don't like it ;)

```
    public sealed class SelectedPositionStateController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private void Update()
        {
#if UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IOS
            if (UnityEngine.Input.touchCount > 0)
            {
                Touch touch = UnityEngine.Input.GetTouch(0);
                
                // do things with touch.position
            }
#elif UNITY_STANDALONE
            if (UnityEngine.Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                // do things with Input.mousePosition
            }
#endif
        }
        
        // !!! USE THIS CODE BECAUSE IT'S OBVIOUSLY BETTER !!!
        // 
        // public void SelectPosition(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
        // {
        //     Vector2 selectedPosition = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        //     
        //     // do things with selectedPosition
        // }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a special reason why you deleted [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65674142/how-to-access-the-click-desktop-tap-mobile-position-using-the-new-input-sy/65681184#65681184) but are now using the code I gave you? ....

Comment: @derHugo yes, your provided solution was correct for one case but this solution had nothing to do with the error I posted. So this error is reproducible even with your code

Comment: Have you tried `context.control.ReadValue<Vector2>()` or `context.ReadValue()` ? Still if my solution was correct and helped you .. why did you close the question then?

Comment: To be fair to the question3r, the new and "improved" input system will drive anyone attempting to use it to the edge of their sanity. and beyond. @derHugo

Comment: I don't see why that old question (and indeed answer) was closed

Comment: i didn't even KNOW THERE WAS a new-new input system, My God

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To achieve the desired outcome you will need 2 [InputAction](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.html). One for the Click, and another for the Position.

Your `MonoBehaviour` will listen to the `performed` event of `InputAction` related to the Click and read the Position from the one related to Position.

The `InputAction` related to Position is optional; as you may catch it with the input system API.

- `Touchscreen.current.primaryTouch.position.ReadValue()`
- `Mouse.current.position.ReadValue()`

For your use case I suggest either:

1. Serialize the `InputAction` directly in the `MonoBehaviour`
2. Use an [InputActionAsset](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputActionAsset.html) and get the `InputAction` from there

---

## OPTION 1 - Direct InputAction

Setup one `InputAction` for the Click, and another for the Position.
Then you might listen to the Click and catch the position from the Position.

```
public class InputWithAction : MonoBehaviour
{
    // --------------- FIELDS AND PROPERTIES --------------- //
    [SerializeField] private InputAction _click;
    [SerializeField] private InputAction _pos;

    // --------------- INITIALIZATION --------------- //
    private void Process(InputAction.CallbackContext callback)
    {
        //get the value from the position
        Debug.Log($"Input action: {_pos.ReadValue<Vector2>()}");
        //use the items below if you want to get the input directly
#if UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IOS
        //gets the primary touch position using the new input system
        Debug.Log(Touchscreen.current.primaryTouch.position.ReadValue());
#elif UNITY_STANDALONE
        //gets the current mouse position using the new input system
        Debug.Log(Mouse.current.position.ReadValue());
#endif
    }

    // --------------- LISTENER SETUP --------------- //
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _click.Enable();
        _pos.Enable();
        _click.performed += Process;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        _click.performed -= Process;
        _click.Disable();
        _pos.Disable();
    }
}
```

The Click action requires 2 bindings.

- Add a Bidning with the + button => set the Path as: Mouse/Left Button
- Add a Bidning with the + button => set the Path as: TouchScreen/Primary Touch/Tap

The Position requires 2 bindings.

- Add a Bidning with the + button => set the Path as: Mouse/Position
- Add a Bidning with the + button => set the Path as: TouchScreen/Primary Touch/Position

Your component will look like this:

[image]

## OPTION 2 - The InputActionAsset

1. Create the `InputMapAsset`.
   From the Editor: *Assets -> Create -> InputActions. Call it "YourMap"*
2. Remove all the actions and then add 2 actions.

A. "Click"  action
Action Type: Button
Binding Mouse => Mouse/LeftButton
Binding TouchScreen => TouchScreen/Primary Touch/Tap

B. "Position"  action
Action Type: Value
Binding Mouse => Mouse/Position
Binding TouchScreen => TouchScreen/Primary Touch/Position

It will look like this:

[image]

You can reference "YourMap" as `InputActionAsset` as a field of your `MonoBehaviour` and catch the `InputAction` with the [FindAction](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@0.1/api/UnityEngine.Experimental.Input.InputActionAsset.html#UnityEngine_Experimental_Input_InputActionAsset_FindAction_System_String_) method, using the string names ("*Click*" and "*Position*").

```
    public class InputWithMap : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // --------------- FIELDS AND PROPERTIES --------------- //
        [SerializeField] private InputActionAsset _inputMap;
        private InputAction _click;
        private InputAction _pos;

        private void Start()
        {
            //enable is required only if you're not using PlayerInput anywhere else
            _inputMap.Enable();

            _click = _inputMap.FindAction("Click");
            _pos   = _inputMap.FindAction("Position");

            //listen from clicks
            _click.performed += Process;
        }

        // --------------- INITIALIZATION --------------- //
        private void Process(InputAction.CallbackContext callback)
        {
            //get the value from the position
            Debug.Log($"Input action: {_pos.ReadValue<Vector2>()}");
        }

        private void OnDestroy() { _click.performed -= Process; }
    }
```

---

### A FEW CONSIDERATIONS

- The new input system was designed so that designers might do everything with [PlayerInput](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.PlayerInput.html) class, without coding. The result wouldn't be as performant as the solutions offered above.
- I setup the mouse/touch to catch one click. You might catch also hold, double click or scroll adding [Interactions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Interactions.html) to the [Bindings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/ActionBindings.html).
- In theory you might achieve the same result using just one `InputAction` for the Touch Screen using `ReadOnlyArray<TouchControl>` from [TouchScreen](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.Touchscreen.html#UnityEngine_InputSystem_Touchscreen_primaryTouch) class, but in that case Mouse and Touch would have a different setup. Read more for [Mouse](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Mouse.html) and [Touch](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Touch.html) support.

Comment: Hm somehow this sounds a bit like you could as well simply use `Input.mousePosition` and `Input.GetTouch(0).position` ... what's the whole purpose of this new system then? ^^

Comment: this looks good to me. But there is no way to move all the code to the editor designer? Because currently there is no advantage ... I was hoping for a universal platform solution. My ugly workaround code is even smaller but yes, it's running in the update loop. But still ...

Comment: was hoping to simply read the click/tap position from the `callback` parameter and that's it

Comment: Since it is much requested I added the solution using the InputActionAsset instead of using the InputAction directly. I do not like relying on strings, but it is another solution. Anyway you want to listen to the button callback, so it doesn't have the mouse position. You can either get it directly, or use another input action from the map (I offered both options in the code).

Comment: I greatly edited the answer. Now also the solution with just InputAction won't require the separation based on platform. @derHugo, you can either get the position with the code, or with an InputAction, but you cannot get it from the callback of the mouse button pressed, because it just has the button press event. You might with the touch screen, but in that case you need to separate the implementation with the #if.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is ok for you, but you can give it a try. So I created two methods: one for mouse movement and one for mouse click. When mouse is moved I record it's position and on click — `Debug.Log` this position.

```
public class InputDebug : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector2 lastInput;

    public void Move(InputAction.CallbackContext callbackContext)
    {
        lastInput = callbackContext.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    }

    public void Click(InputAction.CallbackContext callbackContext)
    {
        Debug.Log(lastInput);
    }
}
```

and input mapping looks like this:

**OnMove**
[image]
[image]
[image]

**OnClick**
[image]
[image]
[image]

**UPD: it works on mobile as well**

Comment: thanks for your help. the problem with that is that mobile does not have a "mouse position" or something similiar. So when clicking / tapping I need a way to detect the click/tap position without storing the last mouse position on move :) thanks but sorry

Comment: @Question3r I've added new bindings for mobile support. It works just like on PC. Check it out.